# Rails 3 & 4 conditional association syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, associations, conditional-statements

Hey I've been trying to upgrade a rails app from rails 3 to rails 4 and one of the things I'm having trouble with is working on a gem that has a conditional `has_one` association that will syntactically work with both versions. See below:

Rails 3 syntax:

```
has_one :foo, 
  class_name: 'Gem::Foo', foreign_key: :foo_key, primary_key: :bar_key
  conditions: proc { proc_logic }
```

Rails 4 syntax:

```
has_one :foo,
  -> { where( proc_logic in where clause) }, 
  class_name: 'Gem::Foo', foreign_key: :foo_key, primary_key: :bar_key
```

It seems that both ways of implementing `conditions` on a Rails association are mutually exclusive (deprecated in Rails 4, incompatible in Rails 3). Is there a way to reach a compromise so that the code will work on both rails versions?

Comment: Rails 4 uses `-> {}` as a scope as well. For example, with the class `User`, you can create a scope `female`, leading to the call `User.female.all ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is pretty flexible with these kinds of things.  What you're asking could be written like this.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  if Rails.version >= '4.0.0'
    has_one :foo,
      -> { where( proc_logic in where clause) }, 
      class_name: 'Gem::Foo', foreign_key: :foo_key, primary_key: :bar_key
  else
    has_one :foo, 
      class_name: 'Gem::Foo', foreign_key: :foo_key, primary_key: :bar_key
      conditions: proc { proc_logic }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, I think this is the approach I'm going to take moving forward. Its a bit ugly but c'est la vie!